# Post request with weird problem in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, next.js, axios

Hi I working in a project using next.js in frontend and express in backend. I start to connect applications and got a weird problem, when axios try to send post request to api I received a follow error:

[image]

I say weird because get requests works, my api has cors config, I using docker in all projects and make some tests

server.ts (backend)

```
import express from 'express'
import { adminJs, adminJsRouter } from './adminjs'
import { sequelize } from './database'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { router } from './routes'
import cors from 'cors'

dotenv.config()
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(adminJs.options.rootPath, adminJsRouter)
app.use(router)
const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    sequelize.authenticate().then(() => console.log('DB connection sucessfull.'))
    console.log(`Server started successfuly at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

api.ts (frontend)

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL!

const api = axios.create({baseURL})


export type ErrorType ={
    message: string
}

export default api;
```

authService.ts (frontend) where problem happen

```
const authService = {
    register: async (params: Register) => {
        try {
            const res = await api.post<AxiosResponse<Register>>('/auth/register', params)
            console.log(res)
            return res
        } catch (err) {
            if (!axios.isAxiosError<AxiosError<ErrorType>>(err)) throw err

            console.error(JSON.stringify(err))
            return err
        }
    }
}

export default authService
```

In docker I test requests using container alias and localhost and get a follow results in situations:

using container alias
get request in frontend: works
post request in frontend: problem
post request using curl inside container: works

using http://localhost
get request in frontend: problem
post request in frontend: works
post request using curl inside container: works
post request using postman: works

docker-compose.yml (frontend)

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  front:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
    - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
    - .:/onebitflix-front
    command: bash start.sh
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL=http://api:3000
      - STATIC_FILES_BASEURL=http://localhost:3000
    networks:
      - onebitflix-net

networks:
  onebitflix-net:
    name: onebitflix-net
    external: true
```

docker-compose.yml (backend)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api: #I use this alias in frontend
    build: .
    command: bash start.sh
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/onebitflix
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      SERVER_PORT: 3000
      HOST: db
      PORT: 5432
      DATABASE: onebitflix_development
      USERNAME: onebitflix
      PASSWORD: onebitflix
      JWT_SECRET: chave-do-jwt
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - onebitflix-net
  db:
    image: postgres:15.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: onebitflix_development
      POSTGRES_USER: onebitflix
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: onebitflix
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - onebitflix-net

networks:
  onebitflix-net:
    name: onebitflix-net
    external: true

volumes:
  db:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect from the browser to the API, you need to use a URL that's reachable from the browser.

The docker-compose service names are only usable on the docker network, so you can't use `api` as a hostname from outside the network.

So you need to change

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL=http://api:3000
```

to

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL=http://localhost:3000
```

in your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Thank you, works here, my first test using GET tricked me because the call is inside a GetStaticProps in Nexts.js, and GetStaticProps is trigged before to arrive in a browser, and in this particular case works